# Do cities under computer simulation continue building great projects?

Tags: simcity-2013

When I have a region cluster of 4 cities in SimCity, I logically start out by building one city, and then move on to build other cities in the cluster.

I move back and forth between my cities to gradually improve and perfect them.

In one of my cities, which is based on tourism, I have a massive cash flow and can therefore import materials needed to my great project - in this case, the Habitat.
This city will deliver the imported materials to the great project, along side the materials gathered from the recycling station (metals in the case).

**If I go to one of my other cities, will the city mentioned above keep delivering materials to my great project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Each city is only active while someone is playing it.  This is called "asynchronous multiplayer".

This allows different amounts of time to pass for each city.

You could start one city which has a surplus of power and workers.  Then stop playing that one and start a neighbor.  The neighbor can use the surplus of power and workers - all while no time passes in the first city.

Materials are gift-able, but not share-able within the region.  Only share-able resources may be accessed while a city is off-line.